# leaflet how to setView according to multiple point

Tags: leaflet

The setView() function accept a center coordinate and . I've fetch bunch of points from Google place API, and I want to set the view to include those point in the view.

I've calculated a appropriate bounding box (int lat and lng), but no idea how to set the view aligned with lat and lng, as the setView() only accept center coordinate and zoom, the zoom seems to be measured in pixel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`map.fitBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds):

> Sets a map view that contains the given geographical bounds with the maximum zoom level possible.

Additionally, you can automatically compute the appropriate bounding box of your POI's using a [Feature Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup) then [`group.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-getbounds):

> Returns the LatLngBounds of the Feature Group (created from bounds and coordinates of its children).

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([48.85, 2.35], 10);

var markers = [
  L.marker([48.84, 2.34]),
  L.marker([48.85, 2.35]),
  L.marker([48.86, 2.36])
];

var group = L.featureGroup(markers).addTo(map);

setTimeout(function () {
  map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
}, 1000);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```